# Power BI Average Per Week

Tags: powerbi, average, dax

I need to calculate the average customer volume per week. I have my measures set up as:

```
Total Volume = COUNT ( Table[LoadNumber] )

Total Weeks = DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[Weeks] )

Average Volume = DIVIDE ( [Total Volume], [Total Weeks] )
```

However, not all customers have volume for every given week. This is a problem because I want total weeks to be constant and not relative to the actual weeks a customer had volume.

For example, if customer A moved 16 loads over the past 8 weeks and actually moved loads during each of those 8 weeks, the calculation will be 16/8 = 2 loads a week.

If customer B moved 16 loads over the past 8 weeks and actually only moved loads during 4 of those weeks, the calculation will be 16/4 = 4 loads a week. For my purposes, this does not make sense and I need customer B to also have moved 2 loads a week.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with DAX? I am rather new to Power BI and have spent many hours searching for an answer on this already. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to count weeks over all loads instead of a specific one. If *some* load was moved during that week, then it gets counted for all of them.

```
Total Weeks = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[Weeks] ), ALL ( Table[LoadNumber] ) )
```

Depending on how exactly your visuals are set up and what filter context to do and don't want to ignore, you may want something different instead of the `ALL` argument I specified.

For example, using `ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[Weeks] )` would ignore all slicers and filters directly on `Table` except filters on the `Table[Weeks]` column.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Using ALLEXCEPT works great! However, when I use a slicer to filter to less than the total number of weeks in my table, I would like total loads to be reactively divided by the number of weeks that the slicer is capturing. Is this possible?

Comment: Try `ALLSELECTED ( Table )` instead.

Comment: ALLSELECTED works but there is still one issue. Using another example, my table has YTD data and now has a customer slicer. Let's say Customer A has moved at least one load every single week YTD. Customer B has only moved 3 loads YTD and they were all in the previous week. Before using the slicer, the averages are accurate; however, after selecting only Customer B, the matrix only shows the previous week where Customer B moved 3 loads and the average is 3 loads/1 week = 3 when I want it to be 3/number weeks YTD. ALLEXCEPT works in the above scenario until a date slicer used to get past 8 weeks

Comment: There's not going to be a universal solution. You need to pick whatever combination of `ALL`, `ALLEXCEPT`, or `ALLSELECTED` is appropriate for your specific situation. When you don't have separate dimension tables for dates and customers, this can get messy and more than I care to troubleshoot without actually seeing the model you're working with.